# Rule for obsolete CSS properties?

Tags: stylelint

I'm looking for a Stylelint (and/or ESLint) plugin/rule that has a rule for avoiding the usage of obsolete CSS properties like [`grid-row-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-gap).

I'd like to believe someone already made this, but I couldn't find anything like it via Google, GitHub, or npm.

A plugin that also does the same for [warning] when using experimental properties/selectors would also be welcomed (e.g. [`:focus-visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible)).

Answer (score 0):

Recently I started to develop a collection of rules in this [plugin](https://github.com/isnotdefined-com/stylelint-plugin).

```
npm install @isnotdefined/stylelint-plugin
```

Refer the plugins and rules inside your `.stylelintrc` file:

```
{
    "plugins":
    [
         "@isnotdefined/stylelint-plugin"
    ],
    "rules":
    {
        "@isnotdefined/no-obsolete": true
    }
}
```

At this point I need assistence to find more obsolete properties and values. Just in case someone knows a public list - let me know.